# Refresh an Oracle Materialized view in a Spring Data Repository

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I need to refresh a materialized view in an Oracle database before I query the Spring Data Repository. I'm attempting to do this via a function in the Repository with a native query, like the following.

```
@Query("BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MY_VIEW', 'C'); END;", nativeQuery = true)
fun refreshMaterializedView()
```

However, I am getting `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` when calling this method, although it works fine when being run directly on the database. What am I doing wrong here? Is there an alternative way to force the materialized view to refresh?

Comment: this might be possible with a `@Modifying` annotation

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks, this worked! If you'd like to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to annotate your method with `@Modifying`. It is really intended for DML statements but works for this as well.

```
@Modifying
@Query("BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MY_VIEW', 'C'); END;", nativeQuery = true)
fun refreshMaterializedView()
```

Comment: per the doc: "@Modifying Indicates a query method should be considered as modifying query as that changes the way it needs to be executed...Queries that require a `@Modifying` annotation include INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and DDL statements. ".

Why we need to annotate the refreshMaterializedView method with @Modifying?