# Spring Data JPA: Not supported for DML operations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql, amazon-aurora

I have written a query for an Amazon Aurora DB, to delete some objects, in my interface extending `CrudRepository`, but when I excute the query It throws an exception!

```
@Transactional
@Query("delete from HotelPrice hp where hp.updateDate < ?1 ")
void deletePriceOlderThan   (Date date);
```

tack-trace for exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from com.gamesa.backend.persistence.domain.backend.HotelPrice hp where hp.updateDate < ?1 ]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:554)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you add stack-trace for exception

Comment: Can you add '@Modifying' on your delete method, this effectively drop all non-flushed changes still pending in the EntityManager. If you don't wish the EntityManager to be cleared automatically you can set @Modifying annotation's clearAutomatically attribute to false

Comment: @Yogi, It works, thanks. Please convert to answer

Comment: Might be considered a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684552/refresh-an-oracle-materialized-view-in-a-spring-data-repository/48772140

Comment: @enLopes - Added my comment as Answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For achieving execution of modifying queries that actually only need parameter binding by annotating the query method with ***@Modifying***.

***@Modifying*** effectively drop all non-flushed changes still pending in the EntityManager. If you don't wish the EntityManager to be cleared automatically you can set @Modifying annotation's clearAutomatically attribute to false

Working code will be:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("delete from HotelPrice hp where hp.updateDate < ?1 ")
void deletePriceOlderThan   (Date date);
```

For further reading:

1. [Spring Repostiories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)